# Are there any cameras with touchscreens which can send touch input wirelessly to a computer?

Tags: tethering, wireless

Is there camera with a touch screen which can send the touches of the user to a computer using wireless?

I want to develop a software so that when you circle a portion of the image on the camera's touch screen, the touch can be seen also on the computer.

Comment: iPad or iPhone?

Comment: Suggest this is migrated to Stackoverflow as it's not really a photography question.

Comment: I agree with Mark — unless there are details we are missing, this doesn't appear to be a photography question. It's a hardware/UI question.

Comment: @Ryan: I tend to agree with the other users here. It sounds like the important part of your app is more about the touch and the transmission of the touches than the picture-taking. Could you explain why your app needs to be able to *take* high-quality photos? If it doesn't, then this question is best migrated.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet for this is a tablet or smartphone with a camera. That should do what you want. Either Apple iPhone/iPod/iPad or Android should do.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anything that exists that does exactly what you want it to, you'd probably need to hack a load of things together to get it to work.